# Terraform : manage specificities over each environment

Tags: terraform, environment, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure, infrastructure-as-code

I have 3 environments to manage via Terraform: dev, staging, prod.

An example of use case is below:

- create a "common" service account for each environment (sa-xxx@dev + sa-xxx@staging + sa-xxx@prod)
- create a "dev-specific" role for this sa-xxx@dev SA
- create a "staging-specific" role for this sa-xxx@staging SA
- create a "prod-specific" role for this sa-xxx@prod SA

**How can I easily manage common & specific resources for each environment?**

Terraform is very simple if all environments are equals, but for specificities it looks more complicated. The goal is have a structural way to manage it, and then to avoid:

- code duplication in 3 distinct folders
- "count" conditions in each tf resource definition

**It should be possible for Terraform to look into current root folder UNION dev/staging/prod folder (depending on the environment).**

The need is very simple but implementation seems so difficult.

Thanks for help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question and so it's hard to answer specifically, but one general answer to this question is to make use of shared modules as a means for sharing code between your separate configurations.

The [Module Composition](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/composition) guide describes some different patterns that might help you in your goal. The idea would be to make each of your configurations share modules wherever it makes sense for them to do so but to also potentially use different modules -- or the same modules but with different relationships/cardinalities -- so that your configurations can represent both what is the same and what is different between each of them.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I had a look on the module documentation but I don't understand how to implement them in my use case without code duplication between environments, as each one will have to call the "common" module :/ Can it be possible for Terraform to look for current root folder AND dev/staging/prod folder depending on the environment ? The need looks very simple but implementation looks so difficult.

Comment: You will indeed need a separate `module` block in each configuration, but I wouldn't typically consider that to be "duplication" because the arguments in each case should be different. All of the elements that are the same between the calls should be inside the module, and so conversely the input variables (what you set inside the `module` block) should be different between each call of the module.

Comment: Yes but what if the resource is exactly the same for all environments ? I mean same instance of one module in each environment will imply duplicated code in different folders right ?

Comment: If there is literally nothing different between two instances of the same module then you can just write a `module` block that specifies the location of the module and nothing else. It is true that the same sequence of bytes will be in multiple files, but each of them is representing different information: that there should be another instance of the module.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put shared resources in a common configuration managed in a [remote state](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/remote). Then in other configurations, you can refer to the shared, remote state  using [terraform_remote_state](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/remote-state-data) data source.

Comment: Hi @Marcin ! We already have dedicated remote states in GCP for each environment on dedicated GCP buckets (1 dev bucket + 1 staging bucket + 1 prod bucket). Could you give some explanations & examples as I don't understand your suggestion ? Thanks a lot ! :)